# await promise.all chained array-methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I need to recursively call an API to walk down child entries, and return the filtered results before continuing. I was initially putting the results in an array, and then doing a `.forEach`, and if I found a match I needed to recurse doing so; however, that didn't work because of the problem described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop). So, I tried to modify the answer to that question, but it's still not waiting.

```
const getDatabases = async (blockId) => {
  let databases = [];
  let childDatabases = [];
    
  const children = await getChildren(blockId);
  Promise.all(children.results
    .filter( (child) => {
      return (['child_database', 'database'].includes(child.type)
        || child.has_children === true);
    })
    .map( async (child) => {
      if (['child_database', 'database'].includes(child.type)) {
        return { id: child.id, title: child.child_database.title };
      } else {
        console.log(`Waiting on getDatabases for ${child.id}`); // 1
        childDatabases = await getDatabases(child.id);
        return false;
      }
    })  
  )
    .then((childDbs) => {
      console.log(`Got childDbs`); // 3, 4
      databases = 
        [...databases, ...childDatabases].filter(dbId => dbId !== false);
      return databases;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

}

app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
  const dashboardPage = await getDashboardPage();
  const databases = await getDatabases(dashboardPage);
  console.log('No longer awaiting getDatabases'); // 2
  ...
}
```

So the question is, why is 2 happening before 3 and 4, instead of after them? Shouldn't `const databases = await getDatabases(dashboardPage);` before 2 be waiting for all the recursive calls that pass through `childDatabases = await getDatabases(child.id);` after 1?

Comment: To answer your question, have you tried `await Promise.all(code)`? Because `Promise.all()` itself  a Promise, or `Promise.all` returns a Promise.

Comment: Aha! Yeah, that makes sense. So the `Promise.all` is hanging out and waiting for the `async/await` inside of it, before it gets to the `.then`, but the parent function just fires off those promises and returns nothing, because no one told it to wait on them.

Comment: Yep, exactly. Now you can self-answer your question since I don't have much time today so I won't post an answer. And writing an answer also improves your knowledge of async-await much more than reading one. I'd give you [a reference to Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Apart from the missing `await`, your function also is missing a `return` statement; and the usage of the variables `databases`  and `childDatabases` is weird. `childDatabases` is overwritten in each `map` iteration, dropping the results from many of the recursive calls. And the `childDbs` result value from your array of promises is never used!

Comment: @Bergi, yes — both of those were errors that I didn't catch until I fixed this one :) I don't use StackOverflow enough to be super confident of the etiquette. If it makes sense, I can go back and edit the post to not have those unrelated errors.

Comment: Actually, one other thing. The `childDatabases` is overwritten is intentional. It's concatenated into `databases` as the recursions unwind, which is ultimately what's returned (the ultimate `return` is also missing! :) ).

Comment: @philolegein Sure, please [edit] the question to include only those things that you actually want to ask about - as long as it doesn't invalidate any of the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer was that I needed to `await` the `Promise.all`. Otherwise, the `Promise.all` is hanging out and waiting for the `async/await` inside of it, before it gets to the `.then`, but the parent function just fires off those promises and returns nothing, because no one told it to wait. So, simply,

```
const getDatabases = async (blockId) => {
  let databases = [];
  let dbsOfChildren = [];

  const children = await getChildren(blockId);
  await Promise.all(children.results
    .filter( (child) => {
```

It's worth noting that for similar reasons, one can not chain more array methods after an `async` one. Otherwise, the next chained method will be immediately passed an array ... of unresolved promises. So, you can't, for example,

```
  await Promise.all(myArray
    .filter( (e) => {
      // do stuff
    })
    .map( async (e) => { 
      // do some async stuff
    })
    .filter( // filter ); // <-- this won't work
  )
```

Instead, you need to wait for the promises to resolve and then do your additional manipulations, so you put it in a `.then`:

```
  await Promise.all(myArray
    .filter( (e) => {
      // do stuff
    })
    .map( async (e) => { 
      // do some async stuff
    })
  )
  .then((myPromisesAreResolvedArray) => {
    return myMyPromisesAreResolvedArray.filter( // filter ); 
  })
```

Or, maybe better as pointed out in the comments, just store the results of the awaited promises (your modified array) in a `const` and go on with your code ...

```
  const myPromisesAreResolvedArray = await Promise.all(myArray
    .filter( (e) => {
      // do stuff
    })
    .map( async (e) => { 
      // do some async stuff
    })
  )

  return myPromisesAreResolvedArray.filter( ... );
```

Comment: "*so you put it in a `.then`*" - given you already use `async`/`await`, the better alternative is to use `const promiseResults = await Promise.all(myArray.filter(…).map(…)); return promiseResults.filter(…);`